# Могу ли как-то использовать TextView вне onCreate?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть функция которая по идее должна возвращать `textView2.setText(n + " ");`, но она находится вне onCreate, а в нем функцию поместить нельзя, что мне делать?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Да, можно использовать в любом методе активити, после того, как в onCreate() будет выполнен метод setContentView() . Если вы подробнее опишите, в чем именно у вас проблема и что не получается, то возможно, помощь по вашей проблеме будет более полезной

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте функцию в любой момент и из любого метода с одним правилом - **после** вызова `setContentView` в `onCreate`

Comment: Не onCreare(), а setContentView() должен быть обязательно выполнен перед обращением к виджетам на разметке